# How to highlight text in PDF programmatically for iPAD ?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, pdf, quartz-core

I am working on an iPad application in which I have to select the text from pdf file and then highlight it. Somebody suggested to use **PDFKitten** but it has an option to select the text using search box to highlight text randomly. I was just wondering how to highlight a text by touch and drag it by finger.I couldn't find any proper library yet. It would be great if anyone share solution for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wrong highlight annotation on apple PDFKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469528/wrong-highlight-annotation-on-apple-pdfkit)