# How to Save/Show PDF Highlight Annotations in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf

I am successfully highlighting text in my PDF view using the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47469528/wrong-highlight-annotation-on-apple-pdfkit).

However, whenever I close and reopen the PDF file, the highlight annotations are nowhere to be seen (invisible).

How do I save and/or display the highlights?

Thanks in advance for helping a noob!

Answer (score 1):

Check out the write operations on PDFKit: [`func write(toFile path: String) -> Bool`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfdocument/write_operations)

If you're using PSPDFKit, saving happens automatically based on certain trigger criteria (like moving an app into the background) but you can manually trigger it via calling [`public func save(options: [SaveOption] = []) throws`](https://github.com/PSPDFKit/PSPDFKitSwift/blob/master/Sources/PSPDFKitSwift/PSPDFDocument.swift) on `PSPDFDocument`.